# `NoSuchMethod` exception even if the class has that public method

Tags: java, jenkins, glassfish, vaadin7

Getting `NoSuchMethod` exception but the class has that `public` method declared with the specific method signature, `MyEntity` has a public method with signature `setProject(Boolean project)` , the following exception occurs only on the remote `glassfish` server and `jenkins` is configure to perform a clean build each time a new commit is pushed to github

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mycompany.domain.MyEntity.setProject(Z)V
    at com.mycompany.CloudProject.mergeToRCI(CloudProject.java:63)
    at com.mycompany.getModifiedIfcFileListValuesWithBIMVAULTApproach(ModifiedIfcFileLists.java:128)
    at com.mycompany.gb.ModifiedIfcFileLists.getModifiedIfcFileListValues(ModifiedIfcFileLists.java:60)
    at com.mycompany.ModifiedIfcFileLists.<init>(ModifiedIfcFileLists.java:44)
    at com.mycompany.MyApp.generateModifiedIfcFileLists(GroupBuilderApp.java:5890)
    at com.mycompany.MyApp.configureMiddleLayoutForRoomcardMenuItem(GroupBuilderApp.java:2196)
    at com.mycompany.MyApp.buildRCILists(GroupBuilderApp.java:2248)
    at com.mycompany.MyApp.menuSelected(GroupBuilderApp.java:1769)
    at com.mycompany.MyApp.changeVariables(MenuBar.java:199)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.changeVariables(ServerRpcHandler.java:508)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:327)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:202)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:95)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1408)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:350)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:198)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

No clue whats causing this :(

Comment: Nearly always a version mismatch. You have an old version of `com.mycompany.domain.MyEntity` floating around somewhere.

Comment: @chrylis thanks for your suggestion, I'll check that

Comment: @chrylis pls post the comment as the answer of this question , jenkins was not performing the clean build properly and old class files caused the error